# Specialized Cycle Computer?

Tags: product-rec

I'm in the market for a cycle computer that runs in cold weather. Does the Specialized SpeedZone Sport Double Wireless ANT+ work in the cold (eg down to 20 degrees F or hopefully lower)? (I just got off the phone with Specialized "rider support" & they didn't know. (Yikes!).)

Comment: How much lower are you planning to go? I'd expect 20 F to be fine if a bit sluggish, but -20F might have some problems (and not even work). [Icebike](http://www.icebike.org/cycle-computers-for-winter-and-ice-cycling/) says that theirs (whatever they use) works though.

Comment: I would hope that any computer would work down to 20F.

Comment: In electronics, Commercial grade is generally accepted as 0C-85C operating range. Industrial grade would be good down to -40C. This is the silicon temp, but a bike computer has such low power consumption its silicon will be at ambient.  Will it operate at 12F - probably, but if it is commercial grade and it failed it is not considered faulty. .

Comment: Most electronics will work in cold weather barring condensation issues.  The bigger issue tends to be batteries.  Modern "light" lithium batteries work for crap in the cold.  Depending on temperatures, etc, I have seen them only get 25% to 50% of the battery life they would have at "normal" temperatures.

Comment: You might need to strap it to your wrist to keep it warm enough to work.   Or fit pogs to your handlebars and keep the unit in there.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You're all giving me great information & proviing great recommendations..

Comment: @SuspendedUser - There is the problem with LCD displays that they tend to get dim and "sluggish" in cold weather.  I've generally not seen this problem much above 0F, however.

Comment: Batteries rely on chemical reactions and any chemical reaction slows down by half for each 10°C temperature decrease. Basic chemistry. Just do the maths! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I could not find the SpeedZone Sport Double Wireless ANT+ manual on line but I did find the SpeedZone Sport Manual on line and here are the spec's

[image]

I would expect the SpeedZone Sport Double Wireless ANT+ model to be similar.  A agree with the comments that say a bit below should work fine but too much below and you will likely lose the Liquid Crystal Display until the unit warms back up to within the specified operating range

Comment: Hi Dafew, You mention the LCD display's performance will suffer in the cold. Any thoughts on how to keep it warm & visible? A respondent above mentioned keeping it on my wrist. I often ride in a winter parka & I can't think of a way to keep the display visible for reading if it's stuck under a glove or in a pocket or something like that.

Comment: CommuterBiker, the suggestions to keep the unit near your body would work but I find them very impractical, placing the unit under a pogie may also work, as it will keep the unit out of the wind and your body temp may contribute in keeping a localized climate above ambient temperature... the problem with this solution is it is not really a guarantee nor would the unit be visible.